# jquery showing table row upon click

Tags: jquery

I have a form within a table. I have 10 inputs within the form. Initially, i'm only showing the first 4 inputs. onClick of the "add more inputs" I want to show another input consecutively. At this time, this jQuery snippet isn't breaking anything else on the page, but it's just not showing the next line.

```
var inputNumber = 5;

$("#addMore").click(function() {

  $("tr:nth-child('+ inputNumber +')").show();

  inputNumber++

});
```

I can't figure out why this would not work...

Comment: Your qoutes doesn't match.

Comment: It might be easier to do something like this: $("tr").eq(inputNumber).show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used double quotes in place of single quotes (or the other way round).

```
$("tr:nth-child('+ inputNumber +')").show();
```

should be

```
$('tr:nth-child('+ inputNumber +')').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('tr:nth-child('+ inputNumber +')').show();
```